# Ensure that systemd timer instances of same template are not running in parallel

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer, systemd-unit

I have a systemd timer template `job@.timer` and a corresponding service `job@.service`. The job runs daily and has a generous `RandomizedDelaySec` of 2 hours. The job has many instances.

Can I tell systemd to try not to run all instances of the templates in parallel?

The jobs have a high network load. Running them in parallel slows it down and it's more important that the job finishes quickly than running on time.

`Conflicts=job@.timer` or `Conflicts=job@*.timer` does not work.

`job@.timer`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run network intensive script for %i

[Timer]
OnCalendar=daily
RandomizedDelaySec=2h
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

`job@.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run network intensive script for %i

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/my/fancy/script.sh %i
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably solve this by adding an explicit lock to the service unit:

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/flock -F /path/to/some/lockfile /my/fancy/script.sh %i
```

This will allow only one instance of your script to run at a time; others will block until the script is complete.

Comment: Thank you. That should work. However, I'd prefer a systemd native solution. Preferably with less hard constraints. It should not be forbidden to overlap the execution of the units but systemd should try to avoid overlaps.